# Why do we need to assume that $s$ is rational to come to the conclusion that this contradicts $s=\sup A$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand the proof of this problem:

> [image]

The proof is:

> [image]

In the seventh line (counting the equations as lines too), they assume $s$ is rational and obtain that $s+\frac{1}{n}\in A$ and $s+\frac{1}{n}>s$ and this contradicts $s= \sup A$. Why do we need to assume that $s$ is rational? We could come to that conclusion regardless of whether $s$ is rational or not, no?

Comment: By definition $A $ is a subset of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I know but I don't get what this means.

Comment: How can $s+\frac 1n$ be rational if $s$ is not?

Comment: Try to think about the following statement: If $s=\sup A$ and $s'\in A$ and $s'>s$, then we have a contradiction (why?).
Now try to think of the following statement: if $s'\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $s'^2<2$, then $s'\in A$. When does this hold for $s'=s+\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @geetha290krm I know, but $s >s + 1/n $ is true regardless of whether $s$ is rational or not, no?

Comment: @student91 I think I understand your questions but I don't see how it relates to my question. I am saying that $s+1/n > s$ regardless of $s$ being rational or not and asking why do we need the step of assuming that that $s$ is rational to come to that conclusion.

Comment: If $s\notin\mathbb{Q}$ then $s+\frac 1n\notin\mathbb{Q}$ and thus $s+\frac 1n\notin A$ so there is no contradiction.

Comment: If it helps, you could replace the scentence "If $s$ were rational, then $s+\frac1n\in A$ and $s+\frac1n>s$, which would ..." with "If $s$ were rational, then $s+\frac1n\in A$. Note that we also have that $s+\frac1n>s$, which together with $s+\frac1n\in A$ would contradict $s=\sup A$."

They do not mean to say that $s\in\mathbb{Q}$ is a requirement for $s+\frac1n>s$.